# Acmsmall and referencing subfloats

Tags: captions, subfloats, minipage, subcaption, acm

This question is following almost directly this one : [acmsmall and subfigures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229174/acmsmall-and-subfigures)

I managed to insert subfigures using minipage but I'm now wondering how I can refer to these subfigures.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtrets]{acmsmall} % Aptara syntax
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \center
    \begin{minipage}[h]{0.35\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../fig/sc1.pdf}
        \subcaption{Original datapath}
        \label{sc1}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[h]{0.35\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../fig/sc2.pdf}
        \subcaption{Datapath and scan-chain}
        \label{sc2}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Insertion of scan-chain in a simple circuit}
    \label{sc_ins}
\end{figure}

Reference : Figure~\ref{sc_ins} works whereas Figure~\ref{sc1} doesn't work.

\end{document}
```

Result :
[image: reference 2 is not working]

How can I add some numbering to this acmsmall subcaption macro ? Or do you have a better way for referencing subfigures ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you sure that this is allowed by the template? It looks as if this is not the desired way, as the subcaptions do not provide any numbering. If you want to have this, you will have to redefine the `\subcaption` command in order to get some numbering (what result do you desire? "Fig.  1a."?). If the template handles subfigures like here, I would tend to use `Figure~\ref{sc_ins} (left pic.)`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
Ideally I would like to have some sort of subfig numbering. I find this template crappy for that reason, why overwrite existing packages ?
But eventually, if this is too difficult to modify, I will have to go with the "(left pic)" workaround... :/

Comment: Why are you using this class then? I do not know it at all. You could try to do `\documentclass[prodmode,acmtrets]{acmsmall}\let\subcaption\relax` in the beginning. Maybe you are able to use the normal `subcaption` approach then. If this works, you could write an answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229174

Comment: Not an option when writing for a specific editor such as ACM :)

Your answer is perfect, this works. Can you write it as an answer so I can accept it as solved? More specifically, I only added the packages caption and subcaption to my MWE + `\let\subcaption\relax`

Comment: Ok, true. But then you should check with them, if you are allowed to number your sub-captions. Please give feedback, if the undefining of `\subcaption` works. Good luck.

Comment: You are right, I will have to check. Can you take into account what I added into my previous comment?

Comment: Oh, cool. I will write the answer to the other post and mark this one here as a duplicate. Thanks for your feedback. Please edit my answer, if I put something wrong there. I will not compile it, as I do not have this class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24620/discussion-between-bamban-and-larifari).